# Apache Spark SQL dataframe filter multi-rules by string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I would like touse Spark dataframe to search contents by 'like'
and　we can use 'or' function do like SQL '||' to filter like this.

```
voc_0201.filter(
  col("contents").like("intel").or(col("contents").like("apple"))
).count
```

But I have to filter a lot of Strings, how could I filter the String list or array to the dataframe?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first define our `patterns` :

```scala
val patterns = Seq("foo", "bar")
```

and create an example `DataFrame`:

```scala
val df = Seq((1, "bar"), (2, "foo"), (3, "xyz")).toDF("id", "contents")
```

One simple solution is to `fold` over `patterns`:

```scala
val expr = patterns.foldLeft(lit(false))((acc, x) => 
  acc || col("contents").like(x)
)

df.where(expr).show

// +---+--------+
// | id|contents|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|     bar|
// |  2|     foo|
// +---+--------+
```

Another one is to build regular expression and use `rlike`:

```scala
val expr = patterns.map(p => s"^$p$$").mkString("|")
df.where(col("contents").rlike(expr)).show

// +---+--------+
// | id|contents|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|     bar|
// |  2|     foo|
// +---+--------+
```

**PS:** the above solution may not work if this is not simple literal.

Finally for simple patterns you can use `isin`:

```scala
df.where(col("contents").isin(patterns: _*)).show

// +---+--------+ 
// | id|contents|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|     bar|
// |  2|     foo|
// +---+--------+
```

It is also possible to join:

```scala
val patternsDF = patterns.map(Tuple1(_)).toDF("contents")
df.join(broadcast(patternsDF), Seq("contents")).show

// +---+--------+ 
// | id|contents|
// +---+--------+
// |  1|     bar|
// |  2|     foo|
// +---+--------+
```